# \newcommand to change language and textcolor

Tags: pdflatex, textcolor

I try to put the command of changing language and textcolor as in my MWE in one command.

I have a long text in Russian. Main language is French (translations and comments). The paragraphs - sometimes two of them - are translated into French with some comments. That means, I have a bilingual text with many changes of `\selectlanguage`. My `\newcommand` is not working.  I am using `pdflatex` to transform it into pdf.

Thank you for your help

marek

Edit: as samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz in his answer pointed out, the `\newcommand{ru}` seems to work. Thank you! Indeed! Here the new version of my MWE:

ps: are there still some superfluous `{}` ?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman,english,russian,main=french]{babel}
\newcommand{\ru}[1]{\selectlanguage{russian}{\color{myblue}{#1}}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.45,0.75}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{russian}%
{\color{myblue}{
В начале июля, в чрезвычайно жаркое время, под вечер, один молодой человек вышел из своей каморки, которую нанимал от жильцов в С -- м переулке, на улицу и медленно, как бы в нерешимости, отправился к К -- ну мосту.

   Он благополучно избегнул встречи с своею хозяйкой на лестнице. Каморка его приходилась под самою кровлей высокого пятиэтажного дома и походила более на шкаф, чем на квартиру. Квартирная же хозяйка его, у которой он нанимал эту каморку с обедом и прислугой, помещалась одною лестницей ниже, в отдельной квартире, и каждый раз, при выходе на улицу, ему непременно надо было проходить мимо хозяйкиной кухни, почти всегда настежь отворенной на лестницу. И каждый раз молодой человек, проходя мимо, чувствовал какое-то болезненное и трусливое ощущение, которого стыдился и от которого морщился. Он был должен кругом хозяйке и боялся с нею встретиться.}}

\blindtext{}

\ru{
В начале июля, в чрезвычайно жаркое время, под вечер, один молодой человек вышел из своей каморки, которую нанимал от жильцов в С -- м переулке, на улицу и медленно, как бы в нерешимости, отправился к К -- ну мосту.

   Он благополучно избегнул встречи с своею хозяйкой на лестнице. Каморка его приходилась под самою кровлей высокого пятиэтажного дома и походила более на шкаф, чем на квартиру. Квартирная же хозяйка его, у которой он нанимал эту каморку с обедом и прислугой, помещалась одною лестницей ниже, в отдельной квартире, и каждый раз, при выходе на улицу, ему непременно надо было проходить мимо хозяйкиной кухни, почти всегда настежь отворенной на лестницу. И каждый раз молодой человек, проходя мимо, чувствовал какое-то болезненное и трусливое ощущение, которого стыдился и от которого морщился. Он был должен кругом хозяйке и боялся с нею встретиться.}

\blindtext{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre] which shows how you used the `\ru` command? It has a lot of unnecessary `{...}`, but seems to work...

Comment: Thx samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for your answer. I did something wrong, defining the `\newcommand`. You are right! It works, without any tweaking. Are there still some superfluous `{}`? I would like to vote your answer as solution ...

Comment: You're welcome! I posted an answer without the superfluous `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already noticed, your macro works as it is. I would however make some small changes: `\selectlanguage{...}` and `\color{...}` are switches and don't take a second argument:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1,OT2]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman,english,russian,main=french]{babel}
\newcommand{\ru}[1]{{\selectlanguage{russian}\color{myblue}#1}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.45,0.75}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\ru{%
В начале июля, в чрезвычайно жаркое время, под вечер, один молодой человек вышел из своей каморки, которую нанимал от жильцов в С -- м переулке, на улицу и медленно, как бы в нерешимости, отправился к К -- ну мосту.

   Он благополучно избегнул встречи с своею хозяйкой на лестнице. Каморка его приходилась под самою кровлей высокого пятиэтажного дома и походила более на шкаф, чем на квартиру. Квартирная же хозяйка его, у которой он нанимал эту каморку с обедом и прислугой, помещалась одною лестницей ниже, в отдельной квартире, и каждый раз, при выходе на улицу, ему непременно надо было проходить мимо хозяйкиной кухни, почти всегда настежь отворенной на лестницу. И каждый раз молодой человек, проходя мимо, чувствовал какое-то болезненное и трусливое ощущение, которого стыдился и от которого морщился. Он был должен кругом хозяйке и боялся с нею встретиться.}

\blindtext{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx again. There was a tiny difference with the `{}` Have had to copy it out your example into my MWE to see the change of the curly brackets - there were no superfluous brackets, but a different order. Hard to understand the difference, but I am not firm in making `\newcommand` definitions.

Comment: @MarekStepanek The outermost pair was missing in your example. The language switch was not contained to your macro but leaked out. I added those. The two sets inside your new command were wrong. So in sum I moved one pair and removed another pair.